# Extern C++ compiled fn in asm

Tags: c++, assembly, linker

I'm following an OS dev series by poncho on yt.

The [6th video](https://youtu.be/-v6uRjpR_0M?list=PLxN4E629pPnKKqYsNVXpmCza8l0Jb6l8-&t=836) linked C++ with assembly code using `extern` but the code was linked as `C` code as it was `extern "C" void _start()`.

In `ExtendedProgram.asm`, `_start` was called like:

```
[extern _start]
Start64bit:
    mov edi, 0xb8000
    mov rax, 0x1f201f201f201f20
    mov ecx, 500
    rep stosq
    call _start
    jmp $
```

The `Kernel.cpp` had:

```cpp
extern "C" void _start() {
    return;
}
```

One of the comments in the video shows that for `C++` a different name, `_Z6_startv` is
created.
So to try out I modified my `Kernel.cpp` as:

```cpp
extern void _Z6_startv() { return; }
```

And also modified the `ExtendedProgram.asm` by replacing `_start` with `_Z6_startv` but the linker complained,

> /usr/local/x86_64elfgcc/bin/x86_64-elf-ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 0000000000008000

then I tried,
Kernel.cpp

```cpp
extern "C++" void _Z6_startv() { return; } // I didn't even know wut i was doin'
```

And linker complained again.
I did try some other combinations & methods, all ending miserably, eventually landing here on Stack Overflow.

So, the question:

#### How to compile the function as a `C++` function and link it to assembly?

Comment: `extern "C"` does __not__ mean compile as `C` code.  It does mean that the name has external `C` linkage.

Comment: No, the `_Z6_startv` is the mangled symbol name if you keep using `start` in the C++ code. You need to use the `_Z6_startv` on the asm side, not the C++ side.

Comment: @Jester is it `start` or `_start` and should the function signature then be `extern void _start()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a confusion between symbols:

The name of your function `start` will be mangled to `_Z6_startv` at compilation which means that the symbols that the linker (and your asm code) can use is `_Z6_startv`. mangling is what c++ compilers normaly do, but `extern "C"` tell the compiler to treat the function as if declared for a C program where no mangling happen so `_start` stay `_start` which means you do not need to change anything from the code you initialy showed.

or if you want to remove the `extern "C"`
what you want to do is:

```
[extern _Z6_startv]
Start64bit:
    mov edi, 0xb8000
    mov rax, 0x1f201f201f201f20
    mov ecx, 500
    rep stosq
    call _Z6_startv
    jmp $
```